# Passing newly created object to an another page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a mvc4 project and I cant seem to figure out how to pass a newly created object from one page to another page.

on page A

im submitting a form to the database which is creating a new object in placing it into the table.

but after the form is submitted I want a confirmation page to appear afterwards.  I dont know how to pull the newly created object from the previous page that saved it to the database.  I could call it with the Id that was made but I dont know how to call it without knowing the id

```
        public ActionResult Pay(int id,Paid paid)
    {
        PaidAdapter cAdapter = new PaidAdapter();
        paid.CId = id;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            cAdapter.StorePaid(paid);
            return RedirectToAction("SubmitPayment");
        }

        return View(paid);
    }

    public ActionResult SubmitPayment(int id)
    {
        var cAdapter = new PaidAdapter();

        var  model = cAdapter.GetPaidViewModel(id);
        return View(model);
    }
    public Paid StorePaid (Paid paid)


        FContext db = new FContext();

        paid= db.Paid.Add(paid);

        db.SaveChanges();

        //return the paidId
        return paid;
    }

    public PaidViewModel GetPaidViewModel(int id)
    {
        var model = new PaidViewModel();
        FContext db = new FContext();

        model.Paid= db.Paid.Where(c => c.PaidId == id).FirstOrDefault();

        return model;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the overload of [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460291%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) that accepts route parameters. Assuming you're using the default route and it has an id parameter the code would be:

```
return RedirectToAction("SubmitPayment", new { id = paid.PaidId });
```